# How to change multiple img srcs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a "star rating" system, 1-5 stars. When the 1st star is hovered, I want just that star's img src to change. When the 2nd star is hovered, I want the img src of both star 1 and star 2 to change. I am using jquery, but it is not working...here is the code:

```
<script>
$('#imgstar').hover(function () {
    this.src = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon_yellow.png';
}, function () {
    this.src = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon.png';
});

$('#imgstar2').hover(function () {
    $("#imgstar, #imgstar2").src = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon_yellow.png';
}, function () {
    $("#imgstar2").src = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon.png';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS `img a:hover`?

Comment: The second handler is wrong, adding `src` property to jQuery object doesn't affect the `src` property of selected elements, you should use `.attr()` or `.prop()` method.

Comment: Also, you should look into using sprites for images that are similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use jQuery like this.

```
$("#imgstar, #imgstar2").src = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon_yellow.png';
```

It must be like this

```
$("#imgstar, #imgstar2").attr('src', '/dev/images/rate_video_icon_yellow.png');
```

-- [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: @Danw check my answer, it has a more effective approach for your problem than repeating the code multiple tilmes

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to select all the preceding siblings of an element, so you don't have to repeat your code multiple times, you can give a coomon class to your images and do:

```
var $rateStars = $('.rate-star'),
    emptySrc = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon.png',
    fullSrc = '/dev/images/rate_video_icon_yellow.png'

$rateStars.hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.add($this.prevAll()).attr('src',fullSrc);
},function(){
    $rateStars.attr('src',emptySrc);   
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/6h4aH/)**

Also you can go the CSS way and add a class to the images on hover instead of changing the src in jquery, which would let you use sprites more easily